# What's the difference between Nokia Qt SDK and Qt SDK?

Tags: qt, sdk, nokia

http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/ has links to both. I get that Nokia version has phone emulators and related stuff. Is there anything else? I'm just starting to work with Qt and am not too interested in phone applications at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [the comparison table](http://qt.nokia.com/products/qt-for-mobile-platforms#qtfornokia). They are actually quite difference. The Nokia one only includes toolchains for mobile (symbian/maemo) devices, while the other includes the standard Mac/Win/Linux toolchains.

If you aren't interested in mobile development, stick to the Qt SDK.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't find that site.